# “Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)”

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Android studio 2.3.3

I have already tried these:

- android.enableAapt2=false (Did not work)
- Hep -> edit custom vm option -> -Xmx2g (Did not work)
- org.gradle.daemon=false (Did not work)
- Invalidate Caches / Restart (Did not work)

Did I miss something?

I am able to just build/make project but this only occures while trying to run the app in emulator or device.

Comment: This isn't a question about Android Studio.

Comment: ok @LunarWatcher, Can you please help me with this?